# Finding largest value in every array's column

Tags: c++

Currently I have a 2D array and I need to find largest value of every array's column and find their sum.

My code seems to not work properly because I'm getting largest values of every row, not column, also the program sometimes prints the same value two times.

I wrote this code based on a tutorial and I don't know where I made a mistake. There should be basic C++ functions (cycles, if statements, arrays).

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m, a[10][10], sum = 0, max;
    cin >> n >> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cin >> a[j][i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        max = a[0][i];

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j = j + 1) {
            if (a[j][i] >= max) {
                max = a[j][i];

                sum = sum + a[j][i];
                cout << max << endl; //control printing to see the values
            }
        }
    }
    cout << sum;
}
```

Input:

```
3 3
3 2 3
7 5 1
6 3 5
```

Output I need to get is `17` but I am getting `19` right now.

Comment: Proper indentation (as edited by t.niese) should hopefully help you figure out *one* part of the problem. For the rest some *debugging* should help.

Comment: You have a flaw in your calculation of `sum` by the way, *besides* the one you ask about: What happens if the largest value is in the *first* row of the column?

Comment: Why are you asking for `m` and `n` as input when your array is limited to 10x10 elements?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I fixed this part I think.

Comment: @TanveerBadar this task is an assignment of my university, we always limit arrays to 10x10.

Comment: See my suggestion below, you should not calculate `sum` without finishing iteration over an entire column first. Imagine what the code will do if a column had these elements {1, 2, 3}?

Comment: Please ensure that you always use proper formatting (especially correct indentation), this does not only help you to understand your code better, but also helps use to easier understand the code. Propper formatting is always the first step in finding problems. And it might help you to use `num_rows`, `num_cols`, `i_row` and `i_col` instead of `m`, `n`, `i` and `j` as this will make it easier to spot and debug if you write the values to the correct place in the array and if you read them correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array has `m` columns and `n` rows.

```
int sum = 0, max = 0;

for( int i = 0 ; i < m ; ++i )
{
    max = 0;
    for( int j = 0 ; j < n ; ++j )
    {
        if(max < a [j][i])
        {
            max = a[j][i];
        }
    }
    sum += max;
}
```

Comment: it's still counting max element of every row, not column

Comment: Maybe your code to store the array is flipping the array? Try looking at the array you are storing in debugger. There is nothing wrong with the code in my answer itself.

Comment: ok, I managed to fix this problem, but there's still another one. if there's same max value in the first and second column, program takes second largest value in the second column and I get the wrong answer...

Comment: Do you want to sum all the occurrences of max value?

Comment: I figured it out, it was my mistake, program wasn't accessing the last row if the array was n*m format. Thank you for the help!